# Rubyで無駄な変数を減らしたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyぽくないコードを書いてしまったのですが、もっとRubyぽいコードは書けないでしょうか。

それぞれのメソッドの仕様：

- *arr*メソッドは配列を返却し、*custom_push*メソッドはそれを受け取ります。
- 最後の要素が4より大きければ、999を配列に挿入する。そうでなければ、そのまま返します。

メソッドの仕様は変えられないのですが、Rubyの良さをより強調できる*custom_push*メソッドの実装にはどのようなものが考えられるでしょうか。

```
def arr
  [1,2,4] # ケース１
  [1,2,9] # ケース２
end

def custom_push
  a = arr
  if a.last > 4 then
    a << 999   
  end
  a
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tap`を使うとRubyならでは、っていう感じがしますね。

```
def custom_push
  arr.tap do |a|
    a << 999 if a.last > 4
  end
end
```

いかがでしょうか？

あと、Rubyっぽいコードに関しては以前僕が書いたこちらの記事が役に立つかもしれません。

[[初心者向け] RubyやRailsでリファクタリングに使えそうなイディオムとか便利メソッドとか](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/dedb3b889ab226933ccf)

こちらもあわせてどうぞ。

Answer (score 2):

`#arr`の性質(冪等なのか否か、コストがどれぐらいなのか)が明らかではないので、変数`a`は必要です。とすると`if`を後置`if`に書き換えるぐらいしかありません。

```
def custom_push
  a = arr
  a << 999 if a.last > 4
  a
end
```

無理に縮められなくも無いですが…

```
def custom_push
  a = arr
  (a << 999 if a.last > 4) || a
end

def custom_push
  a = arr
  a.last > 4 ? a << 999 : a
end

def custom_push
  (a = arr).last > 4 ? a << 999 : a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

custom_push の細かい仕様が不明ですが、
下記のコードはどうでしょうか？

```
def custom_push
   a = arr
   a << 999 if a.last > 4
   a
end
```

後置の if はとても ruby らしいと思います

Answer (score 0):

冪等などはあまり詳しくないのですが、自分であればこうします。

```
def custom_push
  arr << 999 if arr.last > 4
end
```

Comment: これだと、`arr.last > 4` が`false`だとメソッドの戻り値が`nil`になります。

Comment: @suzukis
なるほど、そうですね。`nil`は返しちゃいけませんね。

Answer (score 0):

`arr`メソッドが何度呼び出しても結果が変わらず、
特にメモリに制限がないなら、何度もよべば良いのではないでしょうか。

```ruby
def custom_push
  if arr.last > 4
    arr << 999
  else
    arr
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`custom_push`メソッドは、`arr`の戻り値の配列の状態を変更するメソッドに見えるので、
`arr`の戻り値の配列自身に`cutsom_push`メソッドを定義し、
それを呼び出すといいのではないでしょうか。

```ruby
a = arr

def a.custom_push
  self << 999 if last > 4
  self
end

a.custom_push
```